# dualboot windows 7 behaves as if th left key is stuck but works fine in ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, hardware

### Windows behaves as if the left key is stuck. I have a laptop the onboard keyboard doesn't work nor does the mouse. Only the media keys and the power button work on the laptop i use a usb keyboard and mouse. Everything works fine when running ubuntu the problem only appears as soon as i boot up windows.How do i find out whats wrong/solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to install proper driver for windows for the inbuilt hardware for your device ? You can find those drivers at the official website of your product

Comment: i have an MEDION AKOYA E5312 how do i upload the drivers the pc is almost impossible to use so would there be a way to upload through th ubuntu dual boot or from a live usb

Comment: try reinstalling windows or try to search for a cd that has the proper drivers already installed. to be very honest I am not aware about the product you are using , but you can try using a different iso file burned windows which might have the drivers you need, I experienced a laggy display once because of missing drivers, I used another version of windows which had the drivers I need and that solved my problem having proper display with crisp resolution. Search for more answers somewhere else but ultimately do try this.